# Calling scripts without specifying the path already set in the bashrc file

Tags: linux, bash, path

I added the following $PATH to my ~.bashrc file.

```
ANTSPATH=/home/3rdparty/ANTs/antsbin/bin
export ANTSPATH
```

However, I would like to be able to call the scripts in the bin directory without having to specify $ANTSPATH in terminal.

Now I have to use:

```
$ANTSPATH/script <input> <output>
```

and I would like to be able to simply do:

```
script <input> <output>
```

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add it in `$PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/3rdparty/ANTs/antsbin/bin
```

Comment: Fantastic! I knew it was something very simple.